# Loading Image and JSON

Tags: android, json

Here is the snippet i use to get json from a web service from a project that we are doing. the TAG_CONTENT contains html files with pictures. I can successfully load the listview including the contents of the html, the problem that i am having now is that the image does not load. it only shows a blank space.

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);
            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if(jsonStr != null){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    news = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_NEWS);

                    for(int i = 0; i< news.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject n = news.getJSONObject(i);

                        String newsTitle = n.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String newsDate = n.getString(TAG_DATE_CREATED);
                        String newsContent = n.getString(TAG_CONTENT);

                        Spanned finalContent = Html.fromHtml(newsContent);
                        HashMap<String, String> newss = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        newss.put(TAG_TITLE, newsTitle);
                        newss.put(TAG_DATE_CREATED, newsDate);
                        newss.put(TAG_CONTENT, finalContent.toString());

                    newsList.add(newss);

                    }                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

this is the code for the adapter

```
 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), newsList, R.layout.list_item_news,
                    new String[]{TAG_TITLE,TAG_DATE_CREATED, TAG_CONTENT},
                    new int[]{R.id.newsTitle, R.id.newsDate, R.id.newsContent});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
```

Comment: Did you consider of using Google's Volley library for JSON and Image loading?  Its pretty simple to use and handles all the complicated stuff behind the scene for you. Try it out.

Comment: But how do you handle this HTML content ? Do you have an ImageView in your ListView's row that you want to fill with image url in the HTML ? I think you need to post the code of the listview's adapter and the content.

Comment: Not yet, this is my first time trying to do an android project with json.I want to understand the basic in parsing but I will make read about google volley. .

Comment: @inmyth i am currently text views for the content of the html. I will post the code for my adapter.

Comment: If you only have TextViews then you cannot expect to load an image in it. Android is not too smart it can display HTML content as is in TextView. You need ImageView for images

Comment: try to use AQuery may be it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said you cannot present HTML in TextView as what you normally see on browsers.

Basically you need to create your own custom adapter and layout with ImageView and parse your HTML to get the image element which you then use on your ImageView. Since you are starter in Android, you may want to read a good tutorial about ListView [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html). And of course there are many libraries for http, networking, image loading, etc ([Must have libraries for Android](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries)) available so you won't have to reinvent the wheel.